# How to to install MySQL2 with Ruby Gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm getting the following error when running `gem install mysql2`:

```
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: have you installed the mysql client yet (separate from the ruby)? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/macos-installation-pkg.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about Ruby environment on macOS and I assume it's installed with asdf.

You will need to install openssl with Homebrew.

If this doesn't suffice, then you will also need to adjust your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to account for the location of your libssl.* file. You will have to do it like this:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/something-openssl/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH gem install mysql2
```